# Flexslider continue on pop up

Tags: javascript, flexslider

How do i make the flexslider continue to rotate on any screen pop up or when browser not in focus?

My code used:

```
 // Flex Slider for Homepage
            $('#home-flexslider .flexslider').flexslider({
                animation: "fade",
                slideshowSpeed: 5000,
                animationSpeed: 1500,
                pauseOnHover: false,
                directionNav: true,
                controlNav: false,
                keyboardNav: true,
                start: function (slider) {
                    slider.removeClass('loading');
                }
            });
```

Comment: i have added slideshow=true and it works in MAC but not in WINDOWS. Anyone encountered this issue before?